# Using RegionFunction on multiple plots

Tags: plotting, functions, regions

I realize that the `Plot` function can plot multiple functions of x at the same time, using `{ }`. I also know that the `RegionFunction` option is used to specify the particular region of the domain that you want plotted. My query is whether I can combine the two together and use different `RegionFunction`s on different functions of the same parent `Plot` statement, plotting multiple conditional functions rather than a whole domain:

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
  2\sqrt{x}  & \text{if } 0\leq x \leq1 \\
  4-2x & \text{if } 1<x<2.5 \\
                2x-7 & \text{if } 2.5 \leq x \leq 4
 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes it is the answer i was looking for ..... btw what made my question difficult to understand could you edit it . it seems you understood it correctly .

Comment: Btw I also wanted to know wether different `RegionFunction` can be used in the same plot

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wasn't asking you to edit your answer. Could you edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Have you looked at `RegionPlot`?  For example: `RegionPlot[{(x + 1)^2 + y^2 < 2, (x - 1)^2 + y^2 < 2}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

Comment: I don't want to plot a region i just wondered if the `RegionFunction` Could be used like the `Piecewise` Function

Comment: This is where I get confused:  "I don't want to plot a region i just wondered if the `RegionFunction` Could be used like the `Piecewise` Function."  I don't know what that means.  If you don't want to plot a region, why are you using `RegionFunction`?

Comment: The region function isnt one bit like the regionplot its more like making the plot function plot only some parts of the plot [ref](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html) Mathematica>Visualization and Graphics > Graphic Options & Styling > Plotting Options > Region Function

Comment: I added an example using `MapThread` that may be useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `Show` to combine graphics of the same type:

```
g1 = Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < x^2 + y^2 < 9]];

g2 = SphericalPlot3D[
  1 + Sin[5 θ] Sin[5 φ]/5, {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Mesh -> None, RegionFunction -> (#6 > 0.95 &), PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Orange, Yellow]];

Show[g1, g2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here is one way that you might construct a compound graphic:

```
funcs = {x^2 - y^2, Sin[x]^2 + 2 Cos[y]^2};

regions = {Function[{x, y, z}, 1 < x^2 + y^2 < 5], 
           Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < x^2 + y^2 < 9]};

styles = {Red, Green};

MapThread[
  Plot3D[#, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, RegionFunction -> #2, PlotStyle -> #3] &,
  {funcs, regions, styles}
] // Show
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

You may also find utility in `Piecewise`:

```
pw = Piecewise[{
       {2 Sqrt[x],   0 <= x <= 1  },
       {4 - 2 x  ,   1 <  x <  2.5},
       {2 x - 7  , 2.5 <= x <= 4  }
      }, Indeterminate]

Plot[pw, {x, -1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I find myself wanting to rotate the graphics, though. To bad we can't post CDF versions of `Plot3D` and `Manipulate`.

Comment: @rcollyer what became of LiveGraphics3D?

Comment: Hadn't heard of that before. The last [update](http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/) appears to be in 2008, though.

Comment: @rcollyer it is or was [used extensively on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/LiveGraphics3DApplets.html).  At the moment I cannot get anything to load however; it may be a browser issue on my end.

Comment: Probably your browser. The [Group Orbit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrbit.html) demo seems to work fine for me.