# Graphic using manipulate runs too slow

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

Here is a naive coding of a projection of a point on a sphere.  It runs very slow.  Can it be changed to run faster without losing its essential analytic character?

```
Magnify[Manipulate[
  Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{x, 0, 1}, {0, y, 1}, {x, y, 1}, {x, x^2, 
      1}, {x*w, x*w^2, x}, {x, y, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, 
      y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], (x^2)/
       Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], 
      1/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1]}, {-x/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], -(x^2)/
       Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], -1/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1]}}, {x, -5, 
     5}, {y, -5, 5}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
    Mesh -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 16], 
    SphericalRegion -> True, (*RotationAction->"Clip",*)
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, 
      Directive[Opacity[0.5], Blue, Specularity[White, 50]], 
      Directive[ Red], Directive[ Red], 
      Directive[Opacity[0.5], Orange, Specularity[White, 50], 
       Mesh -> None], 
      Directive[Opacity[0.5], Orange, Specularity[White, 50], 
       Mesh -> None], Directive[Black], Directive[ Black]}], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.01], 
     Point[{{w/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1], (w^2)/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1],
         1/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1]}, {-w/Sqrt[
         w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1], -(w^2)/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1], -1/Sqrt[
         w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1]}, {w, w^2, 1}}]}]], {{w, 1.086}, 0.01, 
   3}], 1.7]
```

Answer (score 6):

You've got a lot going on in your graphic that is possibly causing the slowdown.  I have not done an exhaustive refactoring of your code, but hopefully considering this approach might help you.

First, I pulled apart your graphic and tried to find what was slowing things down.  The `ParametricPlot3D` has a greater effect on the performance than does the `Graphics3D` component.  In the former, I pulled out the various elements and timed how long it takes to draw them:

```
f = {{x, 0, 1}, {0, y, 1}, {x, y, 1}, {x, x^2, 1}, {x, y, 
    Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, 
    y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], (x^2)/
     Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], 
    1/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1]}, {-x/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], -(x^2)/
     Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], -1/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1]}};
time2 = Table[ 
  ParametricPlot3D[f[[1 ;; i]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Axes -> False,
      Boxed -> False, Mesh -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
     SphericalRegion -> True]; // AbsoluteTiming, {i, Length@f}]
```

I performed this analysis with `time1` and without `time2` (shown) the `RegionFunction` getting the following results:

```
time1 = {{1.351077, Null}, {3.455198, Null}, {3.594206, Null}, {6.287360, 
  Null}, {9.004912, Null}, {10.013767, Null}, {14.450210, 
  Null}, {18.088035, Null}}

time2 = {{0.413024, Null}, {0.855247, Null}, {0.887051, Null}, {1.356276, 
  Null}, {2.078317, Null}, {2.454537, Null}, {3.956425, 
  Null}, {5.527316, Null}}
```

I draw from these data that (a) it takes a long time to draw about half of your components and (b) the RegionFunction isn't helping much either.

Add in the specularity directives and I think you need to reconsider your expectations for smooth and quick response times.

In any case, it looks like a large chunk of your `ParametricPlot3D` is updated after moving the slider and it doesn't need to be.  Let's move that outside of the Manipulate then.  (I tried keeping it the Manipulate using `Initialization -> ...` but received time outs.)

```
preplot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{{x, 0, 1}, {0, y, 1}, {x, y, 1}, {x, x^2, 1}, {x, 
     y, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, 
     y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], (x^2)/
      Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], 
     1/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1]}, {-x/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], -(x^2)/
      Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1], -1/Sqrt[x^2 + (x^2)^2 + 1]}}, {x, -5, 
    5}, {y, -5, 5}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
   Mesh -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 16], 
   SphericalRegion -> True,(*RotationAction\[Rule]"Clip",*)
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, 
     Directive[Opacity[0.5], Blue, Specularity[White, 50]], 
     Directive[Red], Directive[Red], 
     Directive[Opacity[0.5], Orange, Specularity[White, 50], 
      Mesh -> None], 
     Directive[Opacity[0.5], Orange, Specularity[White, 50], 
      Mesh -> None], Directive[Black], Directive[Black]}];
Magnify[Manipulate[Show[preplot,
   ParametricPlot3D[{x*w, x*w^2, x}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 16], 
    SphericalRegion -> True,(*RotationAction\[Rule]"Clip",*)
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red]}], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.01], 
     Point[{{w/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1], (w^2)/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1],
         1/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1]}, {-w/
         Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1], -(w^2)/Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1], -1/
         Sqrt[w^2 + (w^2)^2 + 1]}, {w, w^2, 1}}]}]], {{w, 1.086}, 
   0.01, 3}], 1.7]
```

Now you have slightly improved performance, at least in that the elements of your ParametricPlot3D that are not dependent on `w` won't get updated.

I don't know what *essential analytic character* means to you.  I would continue to peel-back your code in order to identify what elements are creating the performance issues.  Then you can decide if those elements are truly necessary.  I hope some of these suggestions are worthwhile.

I suggest taking a look at the following for additional guidance.

- [How to speed up Manipulate and Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37805/7167)
- [Using RegionFunction on multiple plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5671/7167)

Comment: Thanks bobthechemist.  I didn't know or at least understand the preplot technique.  I am going to take your advice and try to eliminate anything superfluous in the manipulate.