# Permuted Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I produce all 3-digit and 4-digit prime numbers [100-9999] in which, all permutations of all digits produce again a prime number, such as 311, 131, 113, ...

Comment: `FromDigits[Permutations[IntegerDigits[#]]] & /@ {113, 337, 199}`

Comment: Hey, I [recognize](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5672/121) the graphic in your profile picture. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select[
 NestWhileList[NextPrime, 100, # < 9999 &],
 And @@ PrimeQ[FromDigits[Permutations[IntegerDigits[#]]]] &
 ]
```

> {113, 131, 199, 311, 337, 373, 733, 919, 991}

Comment: Mmm.. I'm late, sorry. But mine avoids the magic numbers "26" and "1229". :)

Comment: Yes, I suppose there ought to have been a `PrimePi[]` in there… :)

Comment: …but now that I think about it, you can probably avoid the `Select[]` and the needless generation of a big list; just combine `NestWhileList[]` and `NestWhile[]` appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Nice problem. This ought to work:

```
Select[Table[Prime[i], {i, 26, 1229}], 
 (And @@ PrimeQ[FromDigits /@ Permutations@IntegerDigits@#]) &]

(* Results {113, 131, 199, 311, 337, 373, 733, 919, 991} *)
```

Comment: There are no 4 digit primes with this property apparently!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the relevant online-encyclopedia-(of)-integer-sequences [entry](http://oeis.org/A003459) (complete with Mathematica and Haskell programs for generation)

Yes indeed, after the three digit permutable primes it seems to go all repunits (that is, all "1"s)

Comment: @ Theophrastus : Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Just to explore those incomplete sets of permutations of digits:

```
cand = With[{l = PrimePi[100],
    u = PrimePi[10000]},
   GatherBy[Prime /@ Range[l + 1, u - 1], Sort[IntegerDigits@#] &]];
fun[n_] := Multinomial @@ Tally[IntegerDigits@n][[All, 2]]
res = SortBy[Select[cand, Length@# > 1 &], Length];
all = GatherBy[
   If[fun[#[[1]]] == Length@#, Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ #, #] & /@ 
    res, Length];
Column@With[{s = Ceiling[Sqrt@#] & /@ Length /@ all},
  MapThread[
   Length[#1[[1]]] -> 
     Grid[Partition[PadRight[#1, #2^2, ""], #2], 
      Frame -> True] &, {all, s}]]
```

[image]

To achieve the aim this is relatively quick:

```
ans = Module[{l = PrimePi[100], u = PrimePi[10000], cand}, 
  cand = GatherBy[Prime /@ Range[l + 1, u - 1], 
    Sort[IntegerDigits@#] &];
  Pick[cand, 
   Multinomial @@ (Tally[IntegerDigits@#[[1]]][[All, 2]]) == 
      Length@# & /@ cand]
  ]
```

yielding: {{113, 131, 311}, {199, 919, 991}, {337, 373, 733}}

This avoids repeat testing of permutations.